# Using the POST method of a REST API for read operations

Tags: json, rest, api, post, get

In a restful API, POST should be used to create, and GET should be used to read.

Sometimes, for security reasons, you can't pass sensitive variables in the URI. For example, if you have an /accounts API that requires you to pass "accountNumber". If your security team won't let you put that in the URI, then you have to use the POST method instead of the GET method to service the "read" operation, and you can then provide the account number in the request body.

That brings me to my question: If you've used up the POST method to service a read operation, how do you service the "create" operation of the same API?

"/accounts/create" wouldn't be advised because your APIs should be nouns, not verbs. It doesn't seem right to use up a different HTTP method like PUT. This issue has to come up a lot so I'm curious what people are doing to get around it?

Comment: Consider using HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `POST` for this, you are not building a RESTful service. The way I see this, you have 2 options:

1. Accept this, and build a more RPC-like system.
2. Change the id's in your application so that they are not a security risk. If knowing an id is a problem, consider using something else.